# heat map of density ratio of 2 layers of points

Tags: qgis, vector, heat-map

I have 2 vector layers of points:

- one with a point for each house in the city (thanks to osm.org), roughly equivalent to population
- one with a point for each case of cholera in the city

I'm trying to define in which locations I should site new water supply points based on a local attack rate (ie: number of cholera cases / local population).
I've built separate heat maps for each layer (using QGIS heat map plugin), but it's hard to visually figure out hot spots.

So I'm looking for a way to calculate this local attack rate, ideally something like (number of cases within X meters radius / number of houses within same radius) and spit that out as a raster layer. Basically just like a heat map, but using a ratio rather than a simple count.

I'm guessing there's some magic keyword I don't know that will open a swath of solutions. Can anyone point me in the right direction? I'm using QGIS.

Comment: The magic word may be ["density"](http://gis.stackexchange.com/search?q=grass+density): you are asking for the ratio of two density maps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I found:

- make a heatmap of each layer using the Raster->Heatmap plugin.
- use raster->raster calculator to compute the ratio

this seems to give me what I want, the only caveat being that I'm not 100% sure how the calculation is done, considering that my two heatmaps pixels don't perfectly overlap. I read something hinting at "nearest neighbour" algorithm being used in such situation, but I'm not sure how that would affect my result.

Comment: You need to control the output. Most software computes defaults for the kernel and its radius based on the number of data points and their extent; you probably should override at least one of those defaults if you would like the results to overlap.

Comment: Yes, I saw the pixel size settings, but I'm still unsure about shifting the grid so that both rasters actually overlap. Or maybe it doesn't matter if pixels are the same size?